# GHC/GCC Compiling 3rd party libs and dealing with .eh_frame

Tags: haskell, gcc, ghc

As a small example I am trying to compile the Haskell library bindings [curl-1.3.8](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/curl) with gcc-4.8.1.  I am trying to bind against the cURL library version 7.33-x86 on the Win32 platform.

I am curious how other folks are handling linking errors [in GHC] due to .eh_frame sections.  I saw what looks like a relatively recent commit in [/rts/Linker.c](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/rts/Linker.c) that looks like it takes some steps to solve or at least bypass this issue but I am not certain if this is the fix.

I went through with objconv and stripped .eh_frame from Easy.o and curlc.o, and added those sections back into the resulting [Haskell] library.

```
curlc.obj:     file format pe-i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000260  00000000  00000000  000000dc  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  2**2
                  ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  2**2
                  ALLOC
  3 .rdata        00000008  00000000  00000000  00000398  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .rdata$zzz    00000014  00000000  00000000  000003a0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA

Easy.obj:     file format pe-i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         000041ac  00000000  00000000  00000104  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000124  00000000  00000000  00005ffc  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, DATA
  2 .rodata       00000024  00000000  00000000  0000635c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  3 .rdata        00000080  00000000  00000000  00006380  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .rdata$zzz    00000020  00000000  00000000  00006400  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  2**2
                  ALLOC
```

But of course the compiled version of libcurl's object files are riddled with .eh_frame sections.  Should I try to exclude the section as a linking option during compilation?  Would it be easier/"better" to revert to gcc-4.5.x or does the new code in the repo effectively bypass this error?

EDIT: **Supplemental**

I just checked on one of my Linux VMs and the library does have .eh_frame sections in the obj files.

```
Easy.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         000062f9  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  1 .rodata       00000024  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00006340  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .rodata.str1.1 0000007d  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00006364  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .eh_frame     000000d0  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000063e8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
  4 .data         00000260  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000064b8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, DATA
  5 .bss          00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00006718  2**2
                  ALLOC
  6 .comment      00000036  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00006718  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  7 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000674e  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY

curlc.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000206  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000248  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000248  2**2
                  ALLOC
  3 .rodata.str1.1 00000007  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000248  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .comment      0000002b  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000024f  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  5 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000027a  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  6 .eh_frame     000002b0  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000280  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
```

The gcc version is 4.7.3, and I am a bit more confused now than I was before.

Comment: Rein I appreciate the assistance in getting this question scoped correctly.  I would've preferred you to add GCC instead of edit away GHC and LD, since it does occur during linking and is a problem specific to GHC in how it seemingly isn't processing .eh_frame on Win32.  Libraries and executables created against this library in C/C++ run just fine.

Comment: I won't edit the tags, but I don't see how this can have anything to do with ghc or haskell. Curl doesn't have a single haskell file in its source, so I can't understand how GHC could be causing it to fail. The question also doesn't mention ghc once. If your problem truly has something to do with haskell and/or ghc, you need to give more information.

Comment: Fair enough, I can definitely see the confusion.  Mentioning curl-1.3.8 is for the Haskell bindings to the library.  The current version of curl is 7.33 or thereabouts.  My mistake for not being clear.

Comment: When I edited the post there was no mention of Haskell or GHC anywhere in it so I removed those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a trivial sample program using the Network.Curl Haskell library.

```
-- curlTest.hs

import qualified Network.Curl as C

main = do
  (code,str) <- C.curlGetString "http://www.google.com" []
  putStrLn str
```

By restoring the mingw compiler which came with the Haskell Platform 2013.2.0.0.; the version happens to be 4.5.2. [I had previously linked mingw32-gcc-4.8.2 to be the version that GHC uses as I thought perhaps using a consistent version would solve more issues than it has created.]

I am still using the .eh_frame stripped library that was previously created.  However, when trying to load the ghc repl I get the following symbol error:

> ```
> ...
> During interactive linking, GHCi couldn't find the following symbol:
>   curlzm1zi3zi8_NetworkziCurl_curlGetString_closure
> ...
> ```

This is a symbol in curlc.c (an included helper file with the Network.Curl library).  Manually loading the object file ...

> ```
> cmd> ghci -L. -llibcurl -llibeay32 -llibidn-11 -llibrtmp -llibssh2 -lssleay32 -lzlib1 -package curl curlc.o curlTest.hs
> ```

at runtime results in

> ```
> final link ... ghc.exe: curlc.o: unknown symbol `__imp__curl_easy_getinfo'
> linking extra libraries/objects failed
> ```

*MAYBE NOTEWORTHY: Every other dependency is compiled into a shared library*

Not exactly sure of the issue, but I would hazard a guess that I probably should compile the Network.Curl library as dynamic.  There is still some 'meat on the bone' to make this a little easier, but the question has been answered and I can generate a working executable.